# ionic 3 SyntaxError : "unexpected token =>"

Tags: android, typescript, ionic3

Im building ionic 3 **(angular5+es2015)** application for android OS, it's working for android 7,8, and 9 but not for 6 version, and i got this error when startup application :

[image]

Any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the Javascript VM in Android 6 is too old to have support for arrow functions. The solution would be to use a transpiler like Babel to target the older VM, or to rewrite your code to remove uses of ES6 language features.

Edit: I'm sorry, I realized that there is a "Typescript" tag on this question. You might be able to adjust the `target` setting in `tsconfig.json` to output code that is compatible with the older Javascript version. Try using `ES5`, or if that does not work you can try `ES3`.

Comment: im using ES5 but i got always the same issue ! , blank app work fine on android 6.

Comment: You might have a dependency that uses an arrow function (as is described in this forum post: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/different-error-on-different-devices/56959/8). You could try searching for the string `=>` in `node_modules/`. You might be able to configure the framework to transpile dependencies, but I don't know how to do that with Ionic. Or you could replace that dependency.